# React Native Expo app - unable to open app in iOS emulator

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, expo, react-native-ios

I want to run my React Native app in the iOS emulator. Here is what I done so far:

1. I installed XCode, along with its command line tools, and can bring up the emulator without issue.
2. I created an empty React Native app using the Expo CLI, per the instructions here. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started. I am running on Node v10.0.0 on a Mac.
3. Afterwards I install all the necessary dependencies.
4. I then run "sudo npm run ios". This fires up the Metro Bundler as well as the iOS simulator. The Simulator loads up after about 5 minutes of waiting, but my app does not start up.

What am I missing here?

I should note that I prefer to stick with Expo, so I'd prefer not to have to eject.

Comment: Could you try to open the project (its /ios/projectname.xcodeproj) and build it from xcode first and then fo npm run ios.

Comment: @Rik Thanks for the suggestion Rik. However I'm working with a React Native app built using Expo, not an XCode project.